# Is it better call a function every time or store that value in a new variable?

Tags: php

I use often the function `sizeof($var)` on my web application, and I'd like to know if is better (in resources term) store this value in a new variable and use this one, or if it's better call/use every time that function; or maybe is indifferent :)

Comment: better to use function each time

Comment: @diEcho : make an answer, not a comment

Comment: I've edited my answer below with tests - I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR: it's better to set a variable, calling `sizeof()` only once. (IMO)**

---

I ran some tests on the looping aspect of this small array:

```
$myArray = array("bill", "dave", "alex", "tom", "fred", "smith", "etc", "etc", "etc");

// A)
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
  echo sizeof($myArray);
}

// B)
$sizeof = sizeof($myArray);
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
  echo $sizeof;
}
```

With an array of 9 items:

```
A) took 0.0085 seconds
B) took 0.0049 seconds
```

With a array of 180 items:

```
A) took 0.0078 seconds
B) took 0.0043 seconds
```

With a array of 3600 items:

```
A) took 0.5-0.6 seconds
B) took 0.35-0.5 seconds
```

Although there isn't much of a difference, you can see that as the array grows, the difference becomes more and more.  I think this has made me re-think my opinion, and say that from now on, I'll be setting the variable pre-loop.

[Storing a PHP integer takes 68 bytes of memory.](http://www.pankaj-k.net/weblog/2008/03/did_you_know_that_each_integer.html)  This is a small enough amount, that I think I'd rather worry about processing time than memory space.

Comment: Uhm yeah, it also depends after how much you will use your variables or call the function! Thanks :)

Comment: @markzzz - of course - there's no way I can answer your question for an unlimited number of possibilities though.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is preferable to assign the result of a function you are likely to repeat to a variable.

In the example you suggested, the difference in processing code produced by this approach and the alternative (repeatedly calling the function) would be insignificant. However, where the function in question is more complex it would be better to avoid executing it repeatedly.

For example:

```
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
  echo date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Executes in **0.225273** seconds on my server, while:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
  echo $date;
}
```

executes in **0.134742** seconds. I know these snippets aren't quite equivalent, but you get the idea. Over many page loads by many users over many months or years, even a difference of this size can be significant. If we were to use some complex function, serious scalability issues could be introduced.

A main advantage of not assigning a return value to a variable is that you need one less line of code. In PHP, we can commonly do our assignment at the same time as invoking our function:

```
$sql = "SELECT...";

if(!$query = mysql_query($sql))...
```

...although this is sometimes discouraged for readability reasons.

In my view for the sake of consistency assigning return values to variables is broadly the better approach, even when performing simple functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the function over and over, it is probably best to keep this info in a variable. That way the server doesn't have to keep processing the answer, it just looks it up. If the result is likely to change, however, it will be best to keep running the function.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, as a best practice, there is a scalability issue here. It might be that each run of your software only suffers milliseconds of under-performance due to too many function calls, but if your app starts to be used by millions of people, these milliseconds become seconds, minutes and hours of server processing time.

Comment: Wouldn't the same go for the storage of the variable then?  Either way - you're going to go up in processor usage or memory space.  My assumption is that by the time you get to millions of people, you'll continue adding more hardware, which would moot these differences - y/n?

Comment: I just think it is a good practice to get into. If arriving at a result takes several hundred lines to process, or even a database call, then it is a very good idea to store that result in a variable. Since this is clearly true, why not make it your standard practice even for smaller functions?

Comment: I understand the point you're trying to make, but don't think that analogy works for this question at all.  We're not comparing doing a) quick thing vs b) long thing - we're comparing a) tiny computing power to b) tiny storage space.

Comment: To clarify - I'm not saying you're wrong - I just have yet to hear any reasoning by anyone to show that either one is the "correct" or "better" answer.  And since no one can actually give any specifics on data or clarification - I think it always best to go with less code when possible until shown otherwise.

Comment: Maybe this is part of MUCH bigger discussion (cost implications, processor speed VS read/write access speed, SSD etc etc etc) but my instinct is to stick with my method on this until I know specific reasons why it fails.

Comment: @Mild - My instinct tells me otherwise. Anyway, I would not advise markzzz to spend even two minutes changing all his code, for the possibility of gaining hours of server time if millions of people would start using it. If we don't know what's best, clearly, there is no need to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you allocate a new variable, this will take a tiny bit more memory. But it might make your code a tiny bit more faster.

The troubles it bring, could be big. For example, if you include another file that applies the same trick, and both store the size in a var `$sizeof`, bad things might happen. Strange bugs, that happen when you don't expect it. Or you forget to add `global $sizeof` in your function.

There are so many possible bugs you introduce, for what? Since the speed gain is likely not measurable, I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are calling this function a million times your "performance boost" will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I do no think that it really matters. In a sense, you do not want to perform the same thing over and over again, but considering that it is `sizeof();` unless it is a enormous array you should be fine either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should avoid constructs like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array), $i += 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

For, sizeof will be executed every iteration, even though it is often not likely to change.

Whereas in constructs like this:

```
while(sizeof($array) > 0) {
    if ($someCondition) {
        $entry = array_pop($array);
    }
}
```

You often have no choice but to calculate it every iteration.